# Adding an iferror correctly

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Normally I can add an iferror to my formulas fairly easily. But this formula I am using I seem to be struggling:

Formula:

```
=SUM((X15-V15)+W15)/Q15
```

My Iferror:

```
=IFERROR(SUM((X15-V15)+W15)/Q15),"-")
```

what am I doing wrong? I have even tried to add extra brackets.

thanks

Comment: It looks as if you are closing a bracket after Q15 that you shouldn't: try =IFERROR(SUM((X15-V15)+W15)/Q15,"-")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, should have posted as an answer...
It looks as if you are closing a bracket after Q15 that you shouldn't: try `=IFERROR(SUM((X15-V15)+W15)/Q15,"-")`